# Powershell-Error: Permission Denied, UnauthorizedAccessException when running ps1 file as Administrator

Tags: windows, powershell, permission-denied

I`m trying to run a ps1 file as administrator in Windows 10, Powershell 5.1 but the following error appears:

```
Remove-item : Das Element C:\Windows\system32\opengl32.dll kann nicht entfernt werden: Der Zugriff auf den Pfad
"C:\Windows\system32\opengl32.dll" wurde verweigert.
In Zeile:26 Zeichen:5
+     Remove-item -LiteralPath $filepath
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\system32\opengl32.dll:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], Unauthorize
   dAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

in the first line: "the element ... can not be deleted: the acces to the path ... is denied."

What I tried:
`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned ---> [YES]`

Comment: When the computer says "NO" most of the time it is right. ;-)  Do you have to delete this file regularily or why are you using a script for that? Can you delete it *manually* from the GUI via the Explorer?

Comment: Did you try using the `-Force` switch? It could be either that or the dll is in use? I guess

Comment: I presume that most of what's under System32 are protected system files. It is normal behavior to deny deletion. I should point out that file is a hard link pointing to: `C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-opengl_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1081_none_83a2dbec3e867e11\opengl32.dll`  
Not sure if that's presenting any further difficulty.

Comment: @olaf it worked :) I deleted the file and run the script two times again.

Comment: Wow ... this actually raises more questions than it answers. ;-)  But you seem lucky now.  Great. I'm glad it helped.